# Power Query cannot execute query in document A, while identical query in document B executes without issue

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am working on a tool that fetches and processes data from a web API. A relatively trivial query containing only basic operations like filtering and adding conditional columns would suddenly not load, neither the preview in Power Query Editor nor when loading to a table. It gets stuck refreshing indefinitely. I tried copying the query to a new Excel workbook, and there the query executes flawlessly (the preview generates nearly instantaneously and table refreshes in under 2 minutes). Other queries in the first document work fine.

There are no dependencies in the first document that do not also exist in the second. What could be the cause?

Comment: Does the query always work in Document B without fail?

Comment: @horseyride Yes, it has had no issues whatsoever. I also tried making adjustments and using different methods to achieve the transformations in document B that worked well, but when I copied the code to document A I would once again get infinite loading times.

Comment: well, that sort of makes my suggestion obvious (dupe A code into B), but I that doesn't answer your question as to why. It's happened to me occasionally

Comment: It solved the issue yes, a bit of a hassle to transfer everything over but at least it's working. Strange issue, probably some kind of corruption in the file?